# What am I doing wrong in updating this CV in texmaker?

Tags: texmaker, moderncv, cv

I have to update my CV (class `moderncv`) and I have done the essentials, but using various options in quick build is not doing anything. The format is as before, I have just added a section.

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')

    % moderncv themes
    \moderncvstyle{casual}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
    \moderncvcolor{blue}                               % color options 'black', 'blue' (default), 'burgundy', 'green', 'grey', 'orange', 'purple' and 'red'
    %\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}         % to set the default font; use '\sfdefault' for the default sans serif font, '\rmdefault' for the default roman one, or any tex font name
    %\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page

    % character encoding
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                       % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
    %\usepackage{CJKutf8}                              % if you need to use CJK to typeset your resume in Chinese, Japanese or Korean

    % adjust the page margins
    \usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
    \usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
    %\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}                % if you want to change the width of the column with the dates
    %\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{10cm}           % for the 'classic' style, if you want to force the width allocated to your name and avoid line breaks. be careful though, the length is normally calculated to avoid any overlap with your personal info; use this at your own typographical risks...

    % personal data
    \name{sds}{V}
    \title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
    \address{abc}{M.D.U. }{fddssg}% optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the "postcode city" and "country" arguments can be omitted or provided empty
    \phone[mobile]{1234}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; the optional "type" of the phone can be "mobile" (default), "fixed" or "fax"
    %\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
    %\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
    \email{sdsds@gmail.com}                               
    \photo[64pt][0.2pt]{Bh.jpg} 
    \quote{Best way to predict the future is to create it.}                                 
    \makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother
    %   to redefine the bibliography heading string ("Publications")
    %\renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}https://preview.overleaf.com/public/vpctmcqykhmn/images/71b8368a0d520687a842d23e32a816e8b40c73b0.jpeg


    \begin{document}


    \makecvtitle

    \section{Education}
    \cventry{2017-present}{Ph.D Scholar}{University }{fdfg}{\textit{}}{Tfgf}
    \cventry{2013--2016}{MS by Research}{institute}{Pu}{\textit{6.80}}{a,b,c}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
    \cventry{2010--2013}{B.Sc. (Hons.)}{Uni}{dd}{\textit{78.60\%}}{Algebra, Calculus, Analysis, Differential Equations, Statistics, Numerical Analysis}

    \cventry{2009-2010}{Class 12th}{Campus School}{Ro}{\textit{85.80\%}}{}

    \cventry{2009-2010}{Class 10th}{Campus School}{Ro}{\textit{95.40\%}}{}

\end{document}
```

So Now adding one more section after this isn't being updated by quick build and then viewing pdf is just the same? It has been long I last used it. Please remind me what am I missing?

EDIT: I am trying to add this as a section after education section.

```
\section{Achievements}
\cventry{2013-2016}{ scholarship} 
\cventry{December 2017}{NET Qualified - AIR- 24}
\cventry{June 2018}{JRF- AIR - 111}
```

Here is what Overleaf is trying to tell me.

[image]

Comment: The given code compiles without errors. Can you please add the next section? Perhaps you have an error there? Did you get any error message? Check your `*.log` file for error messages.

Comment: It is something I need to do with settings or something in quick build options, I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your edited code is already named in a comment to the first part of code you gave:

```
% arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
```

That means you must not fill them with text, you can left them empty **but you have to write the empty `{}` then!** Class `moderncv` defines command `\cventry` having 6 parameters and one optional parameter not used in your code.

To get your added code compiling you need to add the missing `{}` to command `\cventry` like

```
\cventry{2013-2016}{scholarship}{3}{4}{5}{6} % <========================
```

In this example I simply numbered the `{}` to be able to show you the result in the printed cv ...

With the complete MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{casual}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}

\name{sds}{V}
\title{Curriculum Vitae}
\address{abc}{M.D.U. }{fddssg}
\phone[mobile]{1234}
\email{sdsds@gmail.com}
\photo[64pt][0.2pt]{example-image} 
\quote{Best way to predict the future is to create it.}

\setlength{\footskip}{42.5pt} % <=======================================

\makeatletter\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}\makeatother


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{2017-present}{Ph.D Scholar}{University }{fdfg}{\textit{}}{Tfgf}
\cventry{2013--2016}{MS by Research}{institute}{Pu}{\textit{6.80}}{a,b,c}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{2010--2013}{B.Sc. (Hons.)}{Uni}{dd}{\textit{78.60\%}}{Algebra, Calculus, Analysis, Differential Equations, Statistics, Numerical Analysis}

\cventry{2009-2010}{Class 12th}{Campus School}{Ro}{\textit{85.80\%}}{}

\cventry{2009-2010}{Class 10th}{Campus School}{Ro}{\textit{95.40\%}}{}


\section{Achievements}
\cventry{2013-2016}{scholarship}{3}{4}{5}{6} % <========================
\cventry{December 2017}{NET Qualified - AIR- 24}{3}{}{}{}
\cventry{June 2018}{JRF- AIR - 111}{}{}{}{}

\end{document}
```

showing the result:

[image: resulting cv]

Please see that I added line

```
\setlength{\footskip}{42.5pt} % <=======================================
```

to get rid of the waring about `\footskip`.

Now a last remark: In your added code you get `December 2017` printed in two lines. That looks not very pretty. Please add/uncomment the line

```
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm}
```

to get a bigger first column to place `December 2017` in one line:

[image: second cv]

Play with the length `3cm` for your needs.

Regarding TeXMaker:

You can always compile your code without TeXmaker by switching to your console/terminal. Switch to the directory you have your cv, lets say `mwe.tex` and then type `pdflatex mwe.tex`. Then you get a file `mwe.log` which should not contain error messages (copy my given MWE to your computer to test that). Now -- if you have a bibliography included -- type `bibtex mwe` or `biber mwe`, depending on the used packages -- and type twice `pdflatex mwe.tex`. This has the advantage that you can check the log file (and blg file for bibliography) after each step.

If TeXMaker does not change the PDF after quick build it happend that the quick build failed (as it did with your original code). Usualy it should show error messages or you simply oversaw them.

Depending on your configuration of TeXMaker it can be that the quick build deletes aux files -- with the result the files with error messages are deleted. To get rid of the error with TeXMaker please add your current TeXMaker configuration for quick build to your question! Delete an erase option if used!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to change any of your settings the file quick builds reasonably. It may help after a faulty run to go to TOOLS >Clean to remove any faulty auxiliary files. And then you will need to run your build sequence with the correct number of passes

The issue may be how you are adding the extra section whilst there may be minor issues with your content. For just this question, I simply just cut and paste the section heading from above and added before the \end(document} it works

[image]

```
    \cventry{2009-2010}{Class 10th}{Campus School}{Ro}{\textit{95.40\%}}{}

    \section{Experience}
    \cventry{2017-present}{Ph.D Scholar}{University of Life}{+ TexExchange forum}{\textit{}}{Learning Latex}

\end{document}
```

NOTE that each type of entry has a fixed number of following braces to create a given structured layout

```
 \cventry{Date}{Description}{More}{info}{goes}{here}
 \cvitemwithcomment{Tag}{A fuller description}{Right set comment}
```

so if you are happy with the layout of \cventry but it only has part info you need to include the empty braces

```
\cventry{Date}{Fuller Description}{}{}{}{}
```

Comment: PLZ SEE EDIT...

Comment: Answer updatet to show need to choose the command that is relavent to your content but ensure the braces are a correct number for that command

Comment: Thanks I got it in overleaf atleast. Still Texmaker is not updating it, not sure what is the problem there.

Comment: In Texmaker you may need to clear bad run Tools Clean then run twice again, have added that now to answer